# 3rd party gaming mouse works before login but stops working afterwards

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse, 3rd-party

I replaced my broken gaming mouse with a new one and it doesn't work. The weird thing is that the mouse works when I reboot but only until I login, then the LEDs turn off and the mouse doesn't do anything (as if it is completely disconnected).

My setup is a MacBook Pro (Retina 15-inch late 2013) macOS Sierra.

Comment: vfiskewl, could you please edit your question to include the exact version of macOS Sierra you're using and also the exact model of gaming mouse you're trying to use? Oh, and welcome to Ask Different! :)

Comment: This happens in Safe Mode as well?  *After* you login in while in Safe Mode?  Is this a USB or wireless  mouse?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is try booting into Safe Mode.

**Boot into Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your Mac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Take a note of what happens (i.e. does the mouse work properly, etc)
6. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal
7. Test again when booted normally

Let me know how these steps went and we'll go from there.

Comment: Thanks for thee reply, I did it but I saw no change

Comment: Ok, so just to verify, your new mouse works before logging in, but does not work after logging in, regardless of whether you're in Safe Mode or logged in normally?

Comment: yes this is what happens. It works fine before logging (both in safe and normal mode) and as soon as I fill in my password and hit enter, the leds turn off and the mouse doesn't do anything (as if disconnected)